# Convert SQL data into a string using PHP

Tags: php, sql, string

I have a column of data from an SQL database which I am calling through PHP. I wish to convert these results in to a consecutive string. So, it's a case of converting the result (consisting of a series of strings from the columns) in to a string.

How would I go about this?

At the moment, when I print the data using

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {   
  echo  $row['title'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

it returns each item, but I wish to place these items into a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using the [`implode`](http://php.net/implode)-function:

```
$titles = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $titles[] = $row['title'];
}
$titlestring = implode(",", $titles);
```

An other option would be to concatenate the strings yourself like this:

```
$titlestring = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $titles .= $row['title'] . ", ";
}
$titlestring = substr($titlestring, 0, -2);
```

The first option is better though in my opinion.

Comment: The second option is just so very very unpleasant, and I see far too many programmers do it.  The first one is the only one that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{    
    $myString .=  $row['title'] . " ";
}
```

Comment: In PHP you don't do string concatenation with a `+`.

Comment: @PatrickKostjens : I edited my answer, but + works well as I remember.

Comment: No it doesn't. In a PHP shell you can try `echo "a" + "b";`. It will result in `0`. `echo "a" . "b";` will result in `ab`. What is the `+` at the end of the line doing there?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can handle this much better..

Give a index on the title column and run a query like this.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;  

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title) FROM database.table GROUP BY title ASC
```

example returned data
title1,title2,title3